# Запрос к базе данных с логами работы телефонного аппарата

Tags: sql

Имеется база данных с логами работы телефонного аппарата. Данные хранятся в одной таблице со следующими полями: timestamp - время события, `type_id` - тип события (1 - поступил запрос на звонок, 2 - трубку сняли, 3 - трубку повесили), `incoming_phone` - входящий номер телефона. Если имеется запись о снятии трубки, обязательно будет запись и о завершении разговора. Если на звонок не был получен ответ, запись о снятии трубки отсутствует. В один момент времени телефон способен поддерживать соединение только с одним входящим номером.

Нужно представить в виде: звонок, начало разговора, конец разговора, номер тел.

Я написал вот это:

-- CREATE

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS for_ya_db;

CREATE DATABASE for_ya_db;

USE for_ya_db;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main_table;

CREATE TABLE main_table (
    id INT(11),
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    type_id INT(11),
    incoming_phone INT(11)
);
```

-- SELECT

```
SELECT * FROM main_table;

SELECT tm1.bell AS bell, tm2.start_talking AS start_talking, tm3.finish_talking, (tm2.start_talking - tm1.bell) AS waiting_time,
(tm3.finish_talking - tm2.start_talking) AS talk_time, (tm3.finish_talking - tm1.bell) AS all_time,
tm1.incoming_phone FROM
(
    SELECT timestamp AS bell, incoming_phone FROM main_table WHERE type_id = 1
) tm1,
(
    SELECT timestamp AS start_talking, incoming_phone FROM main_table WHERE type_id = 2 
) tm2,
(
    SELECT timestamp AS finish_talking, incoming_phone FROM main_table WHERE type_id = 3
) tm3
WHERE
tm1.incoming_phone = tm2.incoming_phone AND
tm2.incoming_phone = tm3.incoming_phone AND 
start_talking > bell AND
finish_talking > start_talking
GROUP BY bell;
```

Проблема со звонками без ответа. И ещё я не уверен, что хорошо использую GROUP BY. Вот.
Помогите плз :)

Comment: Данные не обладают целостностью...
10:00:00 - запрос на звонок 1
10:00:10 - запрос на звонок 2
10:00:20 - трубку сняли

С кем говорил человек??

Comment: на звонок не ответили, такое возможно, тогда в таблице должна выводится запись: запрос на звонок, null, null, номер телефона.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Вот почему я ненавижу SQL :D

Comment: AlexWindHope на самом деле структура данных не SQL'ная. При правильной структуре на каждый разговор должна быть одна запись в таблице звонков. Ее можно генерить по этим же данным триггерами по каждому разговору. И тогда все "любовно и прельстиво". Когда есть только raw логи всегда все сложно.

Comment: Вот и я сижу и думаю - почему бы не создавать запись при новом звонке, а потом просто апдейтить поля "ответа на звонок", "завершения разговора" и т.д., тем более, что одновременно может быть принят только один звонок.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - на практике, всегда, когда-то больше, когда-то меньше, работаешь с таким вот месивом. Меня это, мягко говоря, не доставляет. Но этот пример, естественно, не показателен... ( все мы знаем, что бывает гораздо хуже )

Я прекрасно понимаю, что если все делать по нормальному - все будет намного проще и понятнее. И тем не менее, к сожалению, по нормальному делается далеко не всегда.

PS: к тому-же, я не могу быть адекватным, меня, в sql, страшно бесит BEGIN END :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope оптимизация структуры - самое неприятное, когда возникают вот такие задачи. Надо их предвидеть сразу и строить базу верно изначально, искусство в своем роде. Сам не люблю триггеры и процедуры и BEGIN END в них тоже, стараюсь обходиться без них ) Но бывают тупые железки, которые которые умеют только состояние передавать и приходится либо причудливые запросы писать (в итоге могут быть не оптимальными и вызывать дополнительные расходы на индексы), либо триггерами или вообще в клиенте делать преобразования, что может быть еще хуже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно для каждого разговора брать только тот звонок, который был непосредственно перед снятием трубки (перед тем, как положить тоже, будет он же). Соответственно как только известен timestamp звонка, относящийся к разговору, все просто:

```
SELECT b.TIMESTAMP AS bell, s.start_talking, f.finish_talking, b.incoming_phone, (s.start_talking - b.TIMESTAMP) AS waiting_time, (f.finish_talking - s.start_talking) AS talk_time, (f.finish_talking - b.TIMESTAMP) AS all_time
FROM main_table AS b
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT max(b.TIMESTAMP) AS bell, s.TIMESTAMP AS start_talking, b.incoming_phone FROM main_table AS b
  LEFT JOIN main_table AS s ON b.TIMESTAMP<s.TIMESTAMP AND s.type_id=2 AND b.type_id=1
  GROUP BY s.TIMESTAMP) AS s ON b.TIMESTAMP=s.bell AND b.incoming_phone=s.incoming_phone
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT max(b.TIMESTAMP) AS bell, f.TIMESTAMP AS finish_talking, b.incoming_phone FROM main_table AS b
  LEFT JOIN main_table AS f ON b.TIMESTAMP<f.TIMESTAMP AND f.type_id=3 AND b.type_id=1
  GROUP BY f.TIMESTAMP) AS f ON b.TIMESTAMP=f.bell AND b.incoming_phone=f.incoming_phone
WHERE b.type_id=1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79ad2/10)

Comment: спасибо!!! всё збс!!!

Comment: @Максим Шарипов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

######Еще можно палец вверх, по желанию :)